# Armory wallet and bitcoin - newbie questions

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, buy-bitcoins

I made a transaction into my armory wallet but I didnt downloaded blockchain before. What happened to my bitcoin?
Can I access my bitcoins when ill be able to get the wallet online?

Answer (score 1):

A wallet stores private keys, not bitcoins (and a watching-only wallet just stores addresses, *without* their private keys). Your bitcoins are “stored”, for want of a better word, on the global distributed ledger. You can verify this by looking up your address/addresses (**not** your private keys!!!) on a blockexplorer web site such as blockchain.info — this will show you that your bitcoins are at whatever address/addresses you sent them to. You can do this even if Armory hasn't downloaded the blockchain.

In order to *construct a transaction*, Armory needs a local copy of the blockchain and it needs the [public] address/addresses from which you're spending. But the transaction will not be valid until you have *signed* it, and for that, you need the private keys. In a secure set-up (cold storage), you construct transactions in a watching-only wallet (connected to the internet), and you sign them in a full wallet (on an air-gapped computer); such that your private keys are never exposed to the internet.